# How to make multiple floating elements with variable height using position sticky

Tags: javascript, css, position, css-position

I have a list of elements coming from a configuration API. I am using react to convert that data to elements on client side. I need them to be floating (position fixed or sticky) on the right side of my page.

For illustration I have created a simple html

```css
.rail-elements {
    position: sticky;
}
.indicator {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 32;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <body style="height: 200vh">
        <div class="rail-elements" style="top: 0px; height: 100px; background: red; z-index: 4"></div>
        <div class="rail-elements" style="top: 0px; height: 150px; background: blue; z-index: 3"></div>
        <div class="rail-elements" style="top: 0px; height: 200px; background: green; z-index: 2"></div>
        <div class="rail-elements" style="top: 0px; height: 250px; background: yellow; z-index: 1"></div>
        <div class="indicator">scroll down</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now the problem is, I cannot figure out what should be the value of top in style attribute for every element. As these elements are results of data from an API, Height is variable for every element and changes from time to time, See how elements are getting stacked and covering each other's content.

Is there any way I can make elements floating without covering each other?

Following is the result I want to achieve.

```css
.rail-elements {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0px;
}
.indicator {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 32;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <body style="height: 200vh">
        <div class="rail-elements" style="top: 0px; height: 50px; background: red; z-index: 4"></div>
        <div class="rail-elements" style="top: 50px; height: 75px; background: blue; z-index: 3"></div>
        <div class="rail-elements" style="top: 125px; height: 100px; background: green; z-index: 2"></div>
        <div class="rail-elements" style="top: 225px; height: 125px; background: yellow; z-index: 1"></div>
        <div class="indicator">scroll down</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I know, I can find out height of every element after they are mounted and I can use it for calculating top for every element. 
This solution is okay but for me it is too complex, because I may have to do changes in 20+ files, As this component is passing list of elements to several pages where they are mounted. I get mount event on page and not on this component.

Is it possible to do using CSS? or any other simpler way?
Any help is appreciated thanks in advance!

Edit: Some elements of the list may not be floating, and re-ordering is not allowed.

Comment: wrap all of them in the same div and make that div sticky

Comment: Thanks @TemaniAfif but there are some elements which are not supposed to be floating and reordering/grouping of elements is not allowed either.